# UIPickerView wait with didSelect until scrolling animation is done

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

I have two `UIPickerViews`: `pickerOne` and `pickerTwo`. The contents of `pickerTwo` depend on what was selected in `pickerOne`. The name of the selected item for each picker is displayed in a `UITextField`.

An example of the dependency:

If `pickerOne` selects `x`, then `pickerTwo` will display `element1`, `element2`, and `element3`.

If `pickerOne`selects `y`, then `pickerTwo` will display `element4`, `element5`, and `element6`.

I use the following code to do this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView === pickerOne {
        textFieldOne.text = pickerOneData[row].name

        pickerTwoData = // Update the data.
        pickerTwo.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
    else if pickerView === pickerTwo {
        textFieldTwo.text = pickerTwoData[row].name
    }
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView === pickerOne {
        return pickerOneData[row].name
    }
    else if pickerView === pickerTwo {
        return pickerTwoData[row].name
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that these pickers act very weirdly if I select a row in `pickerOne` for which there is only one row in `pickerTwo`.

If i select a row in `pickerOne` which has several rows in `pickerTwo`, and then select the row in `pickerOne` which only has one row in `pickerTwo`. Then I can get a `index out of range` error depending on what I do next.

If I close the `UIPickerView` (`self.view.endEditing(true)`) then there are no problems, but if I just select the row in `pickerOne` which has only one row in `pickerTwo` the error happens.

I suspect this has something to do with the animation which is played when you swipe up on a UIPickerView which makes it scroll since it doesn't update the textfield until it has stopped scrolling.

I'd really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the bug but I'm still very confused. I changed the code in `titleForRow` so that it now says:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView === pickerOne {
        let name = pickerOneData[row].name
        return name
    }
    else if pickerView === pickerTwo {
        return pickerTwoData[row].name
    }
}
```

All I changed was to save name in a variable first then it worked.